Voltage is 140 volts one leg and 90 volts on the other
I have a single phase panel that has 140 volts on one leg and 90 volts on the other to ground under load. Phase to Neutral are fine 121/120 to neutral

Have the power company come and check their wires now.  If their wires are okay, then need an electrician to check your panel/circuits.  Something is not right.  What is your neutral to ground testing at?  Should be ~0.

Check your neutral ground bond in the main panel

N.B. Fix immediately -- fire and shock hazard.

Textbook lost neutral.  The utility delivers 3 wires to your house, and one wire is broken.

If you are reading 140 and 90, to ground, you have no ground If you are reading 121/120 to neutral you are not bonded to the ground. The big question is what else is wrong? What are your readings leg to leg. And yes, you probably do have a broken neutral.
